# Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm writing update code for my add-on. That is to create a Google Docs file that inserts tables, paragraphs, images.... When finished, get the page number of the document, if the page number is odd, insert a page break at the end. Initially I used the following code:

```
var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
    Logger.log(pages);
 if(pages % 2 !== 0)
{
  doc.getBody().insertPageBreak(body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph("")));
}
```

But the result was not as expected. No matter how many pages the document has, I only get a page count of 1. Then I added `doc.saveAndClose();`, to get the following code:

```
doc.saveAndClose();
var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
    Logger.log(pages);
 if(pages % 2 !== 0)
{
  doc.getBody().insertPageBreak(body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph("")));
}
```

Great, the program runs perfectly. The page number is taken correctly and a page break is inserted when the page number is odd.
However, when I copy this code and paste it into the App script editor of another Google account, it doesn't run. The error is `Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`.
I guarantee that the code is copied and not edited. I can't understand why with the same code, when running in another Google account, it gives an error. I really need your help. Thank you.

My complete code is as follows:

```
function stepFiles(continuationToken) {
  var folderID = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('folder_ID');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SpssId = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('AH6').getValue();
  var destinationSpss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpssId);
  if(continuationToken) {
    var files = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken);
  }
  else {
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  }
var k = 0;
while (files.hasNext() && k<1) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var l = fileName.replace(/\D/g,'');
  var g=+l;
 // Logger.log(l);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var de=ss.getSheetByName('tests');
  var sol=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('A77').getValue()).getSheetByName('Solution');
 //var doc=DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
var doc = DocumentApp.create(l);
var docId = doc.getId();
var docIdInss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('A77').getValue()).getSheetByName('link').getRange('A'+l).setValue(docId);
body=doc.getBody();
body.appendParagraph('text....');


//Insert elaments .......


body.appendParagraph('------------ Eand ------------').setAttributes(style1).setBold(true);

body.removeChild(body.getChild(2*(2*de.getLastRow()-1)));
body.insertParagraph(2*(2*de.getLastRow()-1),"").setAttributes(style);
body.removeChild(body.getChild(4*(de.getLastRow()-1)));
body.insertParagraph(4*(de.getLastRow()-1),"").setAttributes(style);
var name=doc.addFooter().insertParagraph(0,'Mã đề '+ll).setBold(false).setAttributes(style2);

doc.saveAndClose();
var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
    Logger.log(pages);
 if(pages % 2 !== 0)//Nếu số trang là số lẻ thì
{
  //Chèn một ngắt trang
  doc.getBody().insertPageBreak(body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph("")));
}
   k++;
      if(k==1){
            return files.getContinuationToken();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is explained in the [`saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) documentation:

> Saves the current Document. Causes pending updates to be flushed and applied.
>
> A closed Document can't be edited. Use DocumentApp.openById() to reopen a given document for editing.

Since you closed the document you cannot use the `doc` variable to edit it unless you open it again.

The reason why you were getting a page count of 1 without using `saveAndClose()` is because `doc` is created as a blank document and you need to save your changes first.

As mentioned in the documentation I quoted above, you can reopen the doc with [`DocumentApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)). You'll need to reassign the `doc` variable and also the `body` variable, since the `body` variable that you are referring to is the one that was created before the changes were saved. It might look something like this:

```
  doc.saveAndClose();
  doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc.getId()) //reopen the document
  body = doc.getBody() // get the new body
  var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
  var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
  Logger.log(pages);
  if (pages % 2 !== 0)
  {
    doc.insertPageBreak(body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph("")));
  }
```

Comment: Actually I already declared two variables `doc` and `body` at the beginning of the code. And as I said in the question, mac runs perfectly in another google account, but copying the code to the second account gives the same error.

Comment: Can you post the full code sample then? As I explained in my post, the `saveAndClose()` method should not even be there, and it's the cause of the exception message. I know it's strange that it only works on one account, but either way, we need the full context of your code to figure out what you're doing with that `doc` variable elsewhere and why adding that function even worked in the first place.

Comment: I edited the post above with the complete code already, 
@Daniel.

Comment: I have a better idea of what happened now. I updated my answer with a new suggestion. Give it a try and let me know if it helps. The only doubt I still have is why your original code would work only in one account. I think it should have worked in *neither* account, but maybe it's related to permissions or something similar.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, you were patient with my questions. It worked very well.